# Best way to search in a array in array - Stacking up arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, performance, comparison

at the moment I'm writing a script which has the assignment to check if all products are still remaining in the database. Because I have +5000 products I want to write the script as optimized as possible.

That is also the reason why I has loaded the entire (+5000) database table to a local array. Because I think it is much cleaner and faster to search in a local array than doing around 5 sql queries per product. And I have already solved 3 out of 5 queries per product. But at the moment I'm catched up at the 4th query.

This query is target to look up if a specified product is still remaining in the database table. I have load the database table into a local array which looks like this:

```
array(5419) {
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(17) "Final Fantasy VII"
    ["price"]=>
    string(5) "11.69"
    ["shop"]=>
    string(4) "9507"
    ["url"]=>
    string(77) "https://de.gamesplanet.com/game/..."
  }
  [2]=>
```

The key `1` and `2` are representing the `Auto Increment ID` of the MySQL database. I do not need them in the array but I didn't know how to solve it better. But the resulting effect of this now is that I have a array in a array...

And here is now my problem. I want to check e.g. if the game `Final Fantasy VII` is still remaining in the array. But one game e.g. `Final Fantasy VII` has multiple price, shop and url entries because I'm programming a game price comparison. So, I'm forced to pack a array in a array because every game can has his own amount of different prices, shops and urls...

But maybe I can leave out the `Auto Increment ID`. Is this a way faster to search for a product? (I do not have the `Auto Increment ID` to search for a product... So, this is only extending my search...)

```
array(5419) {
      array(4) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(17) "Final Fantasy VII"
        ["price"]=>
        string(5) "11.69"
        ["shop"]=>
        string(4) "9507"
        ["url"]=>
        string(77) "https://de.gamesplanet.com/game/..."
      }
      array(4)...
```

Anyway. I need a way to check if a game based on price, shop and url is still containing in my array. But I think it is not the best way to iterate through all `Auto Increment ID` and than iterate again through the array inside and check if the url, price, shop and name are matching my actual product...

Does anyone has an idea how I can check if my product, based on name, price, url and shop, is still remaining in the (array in) array without looping through all products or is there a better way then that?

I would be very grateful about answers and help!

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: I think the array idea is wrong, working with mysql is much better. and don't worry about performance in less than 200 megabyte databases.

Comment: Show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  And explain the problem based on the rows and columns, not "arrays".

Comment: Is a SQL query realy much better? - I mean, I'm forced to loop through each product (5000) and in this product through each price comparision (4-5). So at the end I have more that 25000 sql querys... and that only to check if the price is still the same for each shop... and there are a few other querys left PER product...